# which strings are not repeated in other data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, looking sort of like:

```
Source_name <- c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5")
Target_name <- c("name10", "name11", "name12", "name13", "name14")
values <- c("asd", "213", "kahsd", "a9u", "oau92")
values2 <- c("asdd", "oau892", "kahsd", "213", "213")
dat <- cbind(Source_name, values)
daf <- cbind(Target_name, values2)

dat
Source_name     values 
[1,] "name1"     "asd"  
[2,] "name2"     "213"  
[3,] "name3"     "kahsd"
[4,] "name4"     "a9u"  
[5,] "name5"     "oau92"

daf
Target_name     values2  
[1,] "name10"    "asdd"   
[2,] "name11"    "oau892"  
[3,] "name12"    "kahsd"
[4,] "name13"    "213"   
[5,] "name14"    "213"
```

Each value only occurs once in dat, but may occur more than once in daf (or not at all). I would like to record those values in dat that occur at most once in daf, as per the desired_output data.frame.

```
unique_values <- c( "asd", "kahsd", "a9u", "oau92")
Source_name <- c( "name1", "name3", "name4", "name5")
Target_name <- c( "NA", "name12", "NA", "NA")
desired_output <- data.frame(cbind(unique_values, Source_name, Target_name))

desired_output
     unique_values    Source_name Target_name   
 1         asd         name1       
 3         kahsd       name3       name12   
 2         a9u         name4    
 4         oau92       name5
```

I imagine there's an easy way to do this using apply or something, but Im stumped.

Comment: Combine `sapply(dat$Source_name)` with `%in%`?

Comment: How big are your datasets? Meaning, is efficiency a consideration?

Comment: Well, dat is small (less than 100 rows), and I actually have 40 daf's each of which has about 20,000 rows. So not huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could merge your two data.frames:

```
dd <- merge(dat, daf, all.x = TRUE, by.x = "values", by.y = "values2")
dd
#   values Source_name Target_name
# 1    213       name2      name13
# 2    213       name2      name14
# 3    a9u       name4        <NA>
# 4    asd       name1        <NA>
# 5  kahsd       name3      name12
# 6  oau92       name5        <NA>
```

Then remove rows with values that show up twice or more:

```
dd[unlist(Filter(function(x)length(x)<2, split(seq_len(nrow(dd)), dd$values))), ]
#   values Source_name Target_name
# 3    a9u       name4        <NA>
# 4    asd       name1        <NA>
# 5  kahsd       name3      name12
# 6  oau92       name5        <NA>
```

Or as @hadley pointed out in the comments (thanks!):

```
dd[ave(dd$values, dd$values, FUN = length) < 2, ]
```

Comment: accepted as answer because its much shorter and it worked for me straight away. thank you!

Comment: I think `ave` would be a little more elegant than `split + filter + unlist`

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(dat,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
daf <- as.data.frame(daf,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

fun <- function(x) {
  n <- nrow(dat[daf[,2] == dat[Source_name==x,2],])
  if (n == 0) res <- cbind(dat[Source_name==x,],"")
  if (n == 1) res <- cbind(dat[Source_name==x,],daf[daf[,2]==dat[Source_name==x,2],1])
  if (n > 1)  res <- data.frame(character(0),character(0),character(0))
  names(res) <- c("Source_name","unique_values","Target_name")
  res[,c(2,1,3)]
}

do.call(rbind,lapply(dat[,1],fun))

  unique_values Source_name Target_name
1           asd       name1            
2         kahsd       name3      name12
3           a9u       name4            
4         oau92       name5
```

Comment: What I dont get about this answer is why do you write "dat[Source_name==x",]. What is the "==x" part?

Comment: dat is subset to those lines where Source_name equals x.

Comment: I realised that my question was badly phrased a I had two "Source_name" definitions. So which one are you using?

Comment: There is only one Source_name column in dat.